# Whole system ACK flood attack making internet slow

Tags: attacks, wireless

Over the past few days, I'm noticing that the log of my wireless router is showing an ACK flood attack from various IP addresses. I use a D-Link DIR-600L. I've searched through the internet, also through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967915/syn-denial-of-service-attack) question. But I cannot come to any solution. My ISP advised me to change DNS IP addresses and enter them manually. Doing so still didn't improve the results. In fact, now some websites are not opening, and I'm getting `HTTP Error 404` when logging onto Facebook from chrome, not other browsers. Cleared all history too, nothing changed. MalwareBytes Anti Malware showed that my system is clear. Resetting the router to factory defaults only solves the problem for some amount of time. I use a PPPoE connection, where a wire from the ISP goes into the router, and from there an Ethernet wire goes into my computer.

Here is a part of the log file I recently stored to the computer:

```
Mar 03 22:50:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 22:50:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 22:49:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 22:49:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 22:48:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 22:48:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 22:47:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 22:47:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 22:46:40  Port Scan Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 22:46:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 22:46:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 22:45:40  Port Scan Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 22:45:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 22:45:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 22:42:40 Whole System UDP Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 22:41:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 22:41:40 Whole System UDP Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 22:40:40 Whole System UDP Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 22:40:12 DHCP lease IP 192.168.0.101 to Ayush-PC 90-94-e4-81-d5-69<br>
Mar 03 22:36:40  Per-source UDP Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 22:36:40 Whole System UDP Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 22:35:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 22:35:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 22:13:40 Whole System SYN Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 22:12:40 Whole System SYN Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 22:08:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 22:00:40 Whole System UDP Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 22:00:40 Whole System SYN Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 21:59:40 Whole System SYN Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 21:58:40 Whole System SYN Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 21:51:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 21:50:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 21:50:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 21:49:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 21:49:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 21:48:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 21:48:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 21:47:40  Port Scan Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 21:47:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 21:47:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 21:46:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 21:46:40 Whole System UDP Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 21:45:40  Per-source UDP Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 21:45:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 21:45:40 Whole System UDP Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 21:44:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 21:43:40  Per-source UDP Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 21:43:40 Whole System UDP Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 21:41:40  Port Scan Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 21:41:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 21:41:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 21:41:40 Whole System UDP Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 21:40:40 Whole System UDP Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 21:38:40 Whole System UDP Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 21:37:18 DHCP lease IP 192.168.0.101 to Ayush-PC 90-94-e4-81-d5-69<br>
Mar 03 21:30:24 DHCP lease IP 192.168.0.103 to android-8b858b6c6689a266 94-01-c2-23-e9-e1<br>
Mar 03 21:30:24 Authentication Success 94-01-c2-23-e9-e1<br>
Mar 03 21:30:24 Authenticating...... 94-01-c2-23-e9-e1<br>
Mar 03 21:28:40 Whole System UDP Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 21:27:40 Whole System SYN Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 21:26:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 21:26:40 Whole System SYN Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 21:25:40 Whole System SYN Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 21:24:40 Whole System SYN Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 21:23:40 Whole System SYN Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 21:19:40 Whole System SYN Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 21:18:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 21:18:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 21:15:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 21:15:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 21:11:40 Whole System SYN Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 21:08:40 Whole System UDP Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 21:06:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 21:06:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 21:04:40  Port Scan Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 21:04:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 21:04:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 21:03:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 21:01:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 21:01:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 21:00:40  Port Scan Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 21:00:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 21:00:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 20:59:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 20:59:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 20:56:40 Whole System SYN Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 20:32:19 DHCP lease IP 192.168.0.103 to android-8b858b6c6689a266 94-01-c2-23-e9-e1<br>
Mar 03 20:32:18 Authentication Success 94-01-c2-23-e9-e1<br>
Mar 03 20:32:18 Authenticating...... 94-01-c2-23-e9-e1<br>
Mar 03 20:30:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 20:29:06 DHCP lease IP 192.168.0.103 to android-8b858b6c6689a266 94-01-c2-23-e9-e1<br>
Mar 03 20:29:05 Authentication Success 94-01-c2-23-e9-e1<br>
Mar 03 20:29:05 Authenticating...... 94-01-c2-23-e9-e1<br>
Mar 03 20:26:16 DHCP lease IP 192.168.0.103 to android-8b858b6c6689a266 94-01-c2-23-e9-e1<br>
Mar 03 20:26:15 Authentication Success 94-01-c2-23-e9-e1<br>
Mar 03 20:26:15 Authenticating...... 94-01-c2-23-e9-e1<br>
Mar 03 20:03:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 20:03:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 20:02:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 20:02:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 20:01:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 20:01:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 20:00:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 20:00:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 19:59:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 19:59:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 19:55:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 19:42:53 DHCP lease IP 192.168.0.103 to android-8b858b6c6689a266 94-01-c2-23-e9-e1<br>
Mar 03 19:42:49 Authentication Success 94-01-c2-23-e9-e1<br>
Mar 03 19:42:49 Authenticating...... 94-01-c2-23-e9-e1<br>
Mar 03 19:35:38 Remote management is disabled. <br>
Mar 03 19:35:38 Anti-spoofing enabled. <br>
Mar 03 19:35:38 Block WAN PING enabled. <br>
Mar 03 19:35:37 URL Blocking disabled. <br>
Mar 03 19:35:37 RTSP ALG enabled. <br>
Mar 03 19:35:37 VPN (IPsec) Pass-Through enabled. <br>
Mar 03 19:35:37 VPN (PPTP) Pass-Through enabled. <br>
Mar 03 19:35:37 VPN (L2TP) Pass-Through enabled. <br>
Mar 03 14:05:35 PPPoE line connected <br>
Mar 03 19:35:33 CHAP authentication succeeded <br>
Mar 03 19:35:30 PPPoE: Receive PADS <br>
Mar 03 19:35:30 PPPoE: Sending PADR <br>
Mar 03 19:35:30 WAN Dialup Try to establish PPPoE line<br>
Mar 03 19:35:30 PPPoE: Sending PADI <br>
Mar 03 19:34:31 Manual Hangup Disconnect PPPoE line<br>
Mar 03 19:34:30 CHAP authentication failed <br>
Mar 03 19:34:25 PPPoE: Receive PADS <br>
Mar 03 19:34:25 PPPoE: Sending PADR <br>
Mar 03 19:34:25 WAN Dialup Try to establish PPPoE line<br>
Mar 03 19:34:25 PPPoE: Sending PADI <br>
Mar 03 19:32:57 Manual Hangup Disconnect PPPoE line<br>
Mar 03 19:30:40  Port Scan Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 19:30:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 19:30:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 19:29:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 19:29:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 19:28:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 19:28:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 19:27:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 19:27:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 19:26:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 19:26:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 19:25:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 19:25:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 19:24:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 19:24:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 19:23:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 19:23:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 19:22:40  Port Scan Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 19:22:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 19:22:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 19:21:40  Port Scan Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 19:21:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 19:21:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 19:20:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 19:20:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 19:19:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 19:19:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 19:19:40 Whole System ICMP Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 19:18:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 19:18:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 19:17:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 19:17:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 19:16:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 19:16:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 19:15:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 19:15:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 19:14:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 19:14:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 19:13:40  Port Scan Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 19:13:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 19:13:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 19:12:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 19:12:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 13:41:20 Remote management is disabled. <br>
Mar 03 13:41:20 Anti-spoofing enabled. <br>
Mar 03 13:41:20 Block WAN PING enabled. <br>
Mar 03 13:41:20 URL Blocking disabled. <br>
Mar 03 13:41:20 RTSP ALG enabled. <br>
Mar 03 13:41:20 VPN (IPsec) Pass-Through enabled. <br>
Mar 03 13:41:20 VPN (PPTP) Pass-Through enabled. <br>
Mar 03 13:41:20 VPN (L2TP) Pass-Through enabled. <br>
Mar 03 13:41:18 PPPoE line connected <br>
Mar 03 19:11:16 CHAP authentication succeeded <br>
Mar 03 19:11:13 PPPoE: Receive PADS <br>
Mar 03 19:11:13 PPPoE: Sending PADR <br>
Mar 03 19:11:08 PPPoE: Sending PADR <br>
Mar 03 19:11:08 WAN Dialup Try to establish PPPoE line<br>
Mar 03 19:11:08 PPPoE: Sending PADI <br>
Mar 03 19:10:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 19:10:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 19:10:11 Manual Hangup Disconnect PPPoE line<br>
Mar 03 19:09:40  Port Scan Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 19:09:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 19:09:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 19:08:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 19:08:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 19:07:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
Mar 03 19:07:40 Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny<br>
Mar 03 19:06:40  Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect Packet Dropped<br>
```

Interestingly, almost all of the attacks are taking place at **1 minute intervals**

it's been slowing down my internet. how do I prevent it?

**Edit**: I have the following settings on my router

1. Anti-spoof checking: **ON**
2. Firewall: **OFF**
3. DMZ: **OFF**
4. WPS: **OFF**
5. Enhanced Wireless: **OFF**
6. Preamble: **Short**
7. Channel selection: **Auto**
8. Mode: **802.11 mixed (n/g/b)**
9. Bandwidth: **Auto**
10. 20/40Mhz co-exist: **OFF**
11. Short Guard: **ON**
12. UPnP: **ON**
13. Multicast stream: **ON**
14. DNS Relay: **ON**